# Filter Android listview by only one element of the adapter

Tags: android, filter, android-listview

I m using a listView with a simpleAdapter instantiated like this

```
simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter (getApplicationContext(), listItem, R.layout.item,
new String[] {"title", "description"}, new int[] {R.id.title, R.id.desc});
```

I want filter the listView and I m using this :

```
simpleAdapter.getFilter().filter("test");
```

but the problem all elements filtred contains the charSequence "test" in the title or in the description, what I really want is filter the listView by only description.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleAdapter checks to see if any word in each item begins with the sequence of characters passed to the `filter()` method. You will need to write your own adapter with it's own filtering if you want different behavior. You can start with the source code of SimpleAdapter and make changes accordingly: [Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java)

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each entry and check the description,

```
    if(currentdesc.Contains("test")){
        //Item should be shown
    }
```